# Rawr-created jar throws ClassDefNotFoundError

Tags: jruby, executable-jar

I am trying to use Rawr to turn a simple 3-file Ruby project into an executable jar to be run on Ubuntu. I ran `jruby -S rawr install` to create the Rakefile and set up the directory layout. All my `.rb` files are under the `src` directory at the root of the project. When I run `jruby -S rake rawr:jar`, it compiles all the Ruby files and creates the jar just fine. It then places it in my `deploy` directory along with `lib/java/jruby-complete.jar`.

I try executing the jar from inside `deploy` with `java -jar hg_analyzer.jar`. However, when I do this I am greeted with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" <script>:1:in `require': Linkage error loading compiled script; you may need to recompile 'file:/home/marcw/Documents/hg_analyzer/deploy/jar/hg_analyzer.jar!/main.class': java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/ast/executable/AbstractScript$RuntimeCache (LoadError)
    from <script>:1
    ...internal jruby stack elided...
    from Kernel.require(<script>:1)
    from (unknown).(unknown)(:1)
```

I've also tried running it as `java -cp lib/java/** -jar hg_analyzer.jar`, but to no avail. The `Class-Path` entry in the jar's manifest file looks okay as well. `main.rb` is the main Ruby file.

Running java with the `-verbose` option shows that it *is* finding the JRuby jar and is loading it from the expected location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! The problem was that Rawr was downloading version 1.5 of the JRuby runtime and I have version 1.4 of the compiler on my system.